# stackoverflow error in viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am working on an android application. I have attached 8 fragments with one viewpager for swipe. Its working but when swiping stackoverflow error comes.The following is my fragmentactivity.

```
public class HomeScreen extends FragmentActivity {

public InsuranceFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;

public String value;
public PageIndicator mIndicator;
public static int cPosition = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.themed_circles);

    mAdapter = new InsuranceFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            HomeScreen.this);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    // mIndicator.setCurrentItem(2);

    mIndicator
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                        float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });


}

}
```

and my adapter class is the following

```
public class InsuranceFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context contx;


public InsuranceFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context ctx) {

    super(fm);
    this.contx = ctx;


}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.FragmentPolicyListing.class.getName());
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.FragmentBasicPersonal.class.getName());
        break;


    case 2:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.FragmentationNomineeDetails.class.getName());
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.FragmentFamilyHistory.class.getName());
        break;

    case 4:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.FragmentPolicyDetails.class.getName());
        break;

    case 5:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.FragmentFemale.class.getName());
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.Fragmentmedical.class.getName());
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(contx, com.lic.fragments.FragmentCheckList.class.getName());
        break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 8;
}

// @Override
// public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
// return TestFragmentAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
// }

// @Override
// public int getIconResId(int index) {
// return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
// }

public void setCount(int count) {
    // if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
    // mCount = count;
    // notifyDataSetChanged();
    // }
}
```

}

ANd one of my fragment class is the following

```
public class FragmentationNomineeDetails extends Fragment {


private String nominNameStr;
private String nomindobStr;
private String nominageStr;
private String nominrelationshipStr;
private EditText nomini_name_et;
private TextView nomi_dob_tv;
private EditText nomi_age_et;
private EditText nomi_relationship_et;
private View layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nomination_details,
            container, false);
    Button save = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.save);
    nomini_name_et = (EditText) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.nomini_name_et);
    nomi_dob_tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.nomi_dob_tv);
    nomi_age_et = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.nomi_age_et);
    nomi_relationship_et = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.nomi_relationship_et);
    setlistener();


    return layout;
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView();
    layout=null;
}
}
```

Its working. I can swipe to any fragment but with in 4 or 5 swipe stackoverflow error occurs.
The below is my logcat.

```
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated(Editor.java:1664)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:1563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5974)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14853)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:2276)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13739)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2157)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)    
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13739)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13744)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13739)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13786)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14563)
02-21 14:45:02.817: E/AndroidRuntime(24463):    at       android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3316)
```

I am posting one of my fragments xml file.please have a look and let me know any issues with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.lic.helper.CommonHeader
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</com.lic.helper.CommonHeader>
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/gray_bg_container"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relatve_top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_top_round_background"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Nomination Details"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>




     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relatve_top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_rounded_white_layout" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#F8F8F8"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F1F0EE"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nomini_name_et"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="7.5"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:hint="Nominees Name"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="#F1F0EE"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_name" />

                <TextView
                    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
                    android:id="@+id/nomi_dob_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="7.5"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:hint="Date of Birth"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000" 
                    android:clickable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>





            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="#F1F0EE"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nomi_age_et"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="7.5"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:hint="Age"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="#F1F0EE"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nomi_relationship_et"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="7.5"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:hint="Relationship"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </LinearLayout>





















            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_orange_button_bg"
                    android:text="@string/save"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>







    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your layout can be improved tremendously. Remove the `relatve_top` layout and retain just the `textView1`. Similarly, combine your ImageView and EditText into a single EditText with an embedded `drawableLeft` and remove its parent LinearLayout container. Perhaps this optimisation might help in resolving the SO.

Answer (score 4):

Give it a try by replacing

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nomination_details,
        container, false);
```

with

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nomination_details,
        null, false);
```

Comment: Tried but same result..stackoverflow exception

Comment: @sarath: you might have `too many nested layouts` in fragment.that is why it happens.try to `reduce` the number of layouts.you can `use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout` to decrease the number of layouts

Comment: edited my question with one of my fragments xml file. Please have a look.